# Hard-coding custom menu elements for menu manager

Tags: functions, customization, admin, menus

I realize that one can add custom links through the menu manager but is there a way to manually create such components through the functions.php file?

More specifically, one example here relates to a situation I currently have where I created a custom post type for "events" meaning all associating posts show up like domain.com/events/events-name-abc/ and where the main events page domain.com/events/ is just defined through a custom post type template. As such, when using the admin menu manager interface there is no way for a user to see this main "events" page as an option to add to his menu.

Ideally, I am looking for some example code I can add to my functions.php file which would allow me to define/code in such items manually (with the optional ability to pre-defining custom attributes like a predefined class) and have any of these elements automatically added as options to any of the menu manager meta-boxes or places into a custom meta-box.

Any plugins or code anyone is aware of which extend the menu manager to allow for such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you made a custom post type, you might be have template file for it too, i.e. template-events.php. Then you could make a page titled events, with events slug and set the template to template-events.

After you got an events page, there's must be an Events option on your menu manager.